# Java itext4.x digital signature

Tags: java, itext, signature, digital

I am using itext4 and I know this method of implementation  has been removed in new versions but I am able to generate pdf but its damaged.
Appearance method setcrypto is used to sign.
I added sign field while creating document.
Later open same pdf and apply sign  logic as mentioned in itext in action 2nd edition page 397.

First stamper.close give null pointer exception and next if i comment that line and generate pdf ,the pdf wont open or its damaged

Please advise I am using itext 4.2.1 jar

Comment: Add the code you mentioned. For you the [following page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130329022247/http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html) is probably helpful.

Comment: Indeed, show your pivotal code and also share example result files of it. Furthermore, there is no iText 4.2.1 by iText Software BV, there merely was an internal tag 4.2.0. Thus, your 4.2.1 contains changes by another party. There are different parties who forked iText at that 4.2.0 tag and created a 4.2.1 with their own changes, so it is not clear what code *your itext 4.2.1 jar* contains. So please clarify this, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create digital signature after setting visible signature with 3 param method.
Adding field while generating pdf and later using visible method by passing one param singature field didn't help me.

Thanks for your support.